# Is there a fast way to send HTTP post with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, http, power-automate

Currently i am using the “When an HTTP request is received” trigger in power automate.
I am sending the HTTP with the VBA code below.
The issue is it is very slow. Sometimes taking nearly a full second.
That delay is very noticeable to the user.
Is there a faster way to send the HTTP post?

```vb
'@Folder("VBAProject")
Dim x As Integer
Sub Button1_Click()

x = x + 1
'Dim Req As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
'Set Req = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    reqBody = "{'BOL':'" & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 3).Value & _
              "','Details':'" & "DETAILS" & _
              "','DateTime':'" & Now & _
              "','Status':'" & x & _
              "','User':'" & Application.UserName & "'}"""
              
              
              
              
                  'Assign request url to variable
    reqURL = "https://AZURE URL GOES HERE"
    
    'Create HTTP Oject
    Set Req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    'Send HTTP request
    Req.Open "POST", reqURL, False
    Req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    Req.send reqBody

    

End Sub
```

Comment: That one second is likely almost certainly mostly not to do with sending the request, but with waiting for the response.  So try sending the POST asynchronously - http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Comment: @TimWilliams Changing False to True seems to send it asynchronously. Is it that simple?

Comment: If you don't care about the response then that might be enough.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't care about the response for now. But if i wanted to care is OnReadyStateChange what i would need?

Comment: If you later need the response, then follow the steps described in the link I posted.